Weak formulation of the homogeneous Dirichlet Problem
I am studying the weak formulation of the Dirichlet problem on a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and I came up with the following questions:
What are the conditions on $\Omega$ (more precisely on $\partial\Omega$) for the formulation to make sense? Does some kind of regularity of the boundary must be assumed to pose the weak formulation?
Thanks!

At the very least, you need enough boundary regularity so that the trace operator is well-defined. Typically this is taken to be Lipschitz

It depends on how you set up the problem. Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ be open and consider the homogeneous Dirichlet problem: \begin{align*} \tag{$\ast$}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u =0, &\text{in } \Omega \\
u =g, &\text{on } \partial\Omega. 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
If we assume $g\in H^1(\Omega)$ then one way to formulate the problem $(\ast)$ is to say $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ is a weak solution to $(\ast)$ if $u-g\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $$ \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx = 0, \qquad \text{for all } v\in H^1_0(\Omega).  $$ Here we use the definition that $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ with respect to the $H^1(\Omega)$ norm. This does not require any assumptions on the boundary regularity of $\Omega$; however, it does require that $g$ be defined in $\Omega$ not just $\partial \Omega$.
If you only want $g$ to be defined on $\partial \Omega$ then cannot proceed as above. If we have $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ then another way to formulate the problem $(\ast)$ is to $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ is a weak solution to $(\ast)$ if  $$ \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx = 0, \qquad \text{for all } v\in H^1_0(\Omega)  $$ and $Tu=g$ where $T:H^1(\Omega) \to H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ is the trace operator. This does require regularity on the boundary since we need the trace operator to exist. As mentioned in the comments, Lipschitz regularity is sufficient for the existence of the trace operator, however it is possible to relax this further.
